# How to translate database field values?

Tags: database

I cannot find information on how translate database field values. On my site I use Support Ticketing System module. If I'm trying translate interface to German (for example) everithing is ok except Status field (Status field is reffering to support ticket status - new, in progress, closed). I can see in the database all these values (new, in progress, closed) in certain table. But how to translate them? 
The built-in Drupal interface translation does not recognize these values.

Can you advise the correct way for translation of these field values?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Field Translation module, a submodule (i18n_field) of the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module. Some more details about it (from the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279346)):

> ... allows for translation of text associated with a field's settings including the label, help text, default value, and list options. Translation of these field settings can be added through the 'Translate interface' pages (`Administration > Configuration > Regional and language > Translate interface`).

Especially the "***list options***" mentioned above seem to be what you're looking for.